# What data structure would fit a sequential event dispatch system of events and listeners?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to find a suitable data structure for the following case. I have written a simple event dispatch system with events and listeners. The system is **completely sequential**, so no concurrency and synchronization issues whatsoever.

#### Requirements and Thoughts

- Each listener registers to a predefined (compile time) 1 or more types of events.
- Listeners can register and deregister during runtime.
- The order in which listeners register must be maintained since it is the order in which they receive events (listeners are always added at the end, but can be removed from anywhere).
- An event type can have 0 or more listeners registered to receive it at any time.

A visualization of this relationship can be explained as a table:

```
       | Listener1 | Listener2 | Listener3 | Listner5
-----------------------------------------------------
Event1 |     X     |           |     X     |    X
-----------------------------------------------------
Event2 |           |     X     |     X     |    X
-----------------------------------------------------
Event3 |           |           |           |
-----------------------------------------------------
Event4 |           |           |           |    X
-----------------------------------------------------
```

- The order of the rows is irrelevant.
- The order of the columns must be maintained.
- Columns can be added and removed.
- The number of rows is constant during runtime.

My thoughts are:

- When dispatching an event, I need to know which listeners are registered to receive the event type. I'm thinking about an `Event -> Collection<Listener>` mapping where the keys are unordered. The collection of listeners needs to maintain insertion order (or not, if the following point can be used for this instead).
- I need to keep a collection of listeners that maintains insertion order regardless of the events they are registered to (this demand comes from the objects the listeners are attached to). Because even if the `Collection<Listener>` above is insertion-ordered, it's per event type and not global. I'm thinking about an `OrderedCollection<Listener>`.
- When deregistering, I need to find all the event types a listener has registered to so it can be remove. I'm thinking about a `Listener -> Collection<Event>`, unless the mapping in the first point can do a `removeAll(Listener)` operation on the lists in the value position, but this can leave empty lists instead of completely removing the key.

It seems to me like a bidirectional multimap would fit this case. The backing multimaps are an `UnorderedMap<Event, OrderedCollection<Listener>>` and an `OrderedMap<Listener, UnorderedCollection<Event>>`. The `OrderedCollection<Listener>` might not need to be ordered if the ordering from the `OrderedMap` can be used. Obviously, any unordered data structure can be ordered, but it's unnecessary.

Alternatively, I've seen ideas of a single multimap with a `reverse`/`invert` operation to get the opposite mapping. My concern is twofold:

1. I don't know if one side can have its keys ordered while the other doesn't.
2. This seems like an expensive operation, and if i need to reverse the mapping all the time it can be inefficient.

#### Pseudocode usage

Registering a listener:

```
// somewhere
Listener1 listener = new Listener1();
listener.register(); 

// class definition
class Listener1 extends AbstractListener {

    void register() {

        DataStructure.put(Event1.class, this);
        DataStructure.put(Event2.class, this);

        // or
                                 // some collection
        DataStructure.put(this, [Event1.class, Event2.class])
    }
}
```

Dispatching an event:

```
// somewhere
EventManager.dispatch(new Event2());

// class definition
class EventManager {

    static void dispatch(Event event) {

        OrderedCollection<Listener> listeners = DataStructure.get(event);
        listeners.forEach(l -> l.processEvent(event)); // forEach maintains the order
    }
}
```

Deregistering a listener:

```
Listener2 listener = ...;        // got it from somewhere
DataStructure.remove(listener);  // remove from everywhere and if a key is left with an empty list remove that key
```

#### Final Details and Question

If it matters, there are about 30 event types and the amount of concurrent registered listeners is O(10), though over the lifetime of the program there could be O(100) listeners - most of them deregister and GC'd.

A note about the ordering. Since the listeners have an incremental unique `int id` field, I might be able to ensure that ordering by id number is equivalent to ordering by registration (insertion) order. The discrepancy currently is that the id is set on initialization of the listener, while registration is done afterwards (and another listener could be both created and registered in that gap). If there is an advantage to using sorted collections over ordered collections in this case, I can put in some work to guarantee that sorting by id is equivalent to insertion order.

What data structure(s) would fit my needs? Do I need to write my own (I rather not reinvent the wheel) or is there one(s) implemented already (Guava, I'm looking at you)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at several options and with some basic theoretical considerations I found a solution.

```
Map<Event, Collection<Listener>> // Event stands for Class<? extends Event>
```

where both the keys and and the listeners per key are ordered.

#### Theoretical considerations

Given a map (multimap) of `Map<Event, Collection<Listener>>`, it is possible to get the (global) insertion order of the listeners i.f.f both the keys and the collection of values are insertion-ordered. I won't give a proof here, only a short explanation. This data structure is equivalent to an ordered collection of ordered collections. Performing a flatten operation will result in a single ordered collection with duplicates. Then removing the duplicates by eliminating subsequent occurrences will result in a collection ordered by insertion order.

It is interesting to see how the global listener insertion order is not maintained when either or both of the mapping and the values collection do not maintain insertion order.

Theory aside, such a data structure:

- Maintains insertion order of listeners, both globally and per key, during insertion and removal operations.
- Allows an easy event dispatching, `Event -> <Listener>`, by virtue of the map.
- Does not allow an easy deregistration of `Listener -> <Event>` (not bidirectional).
- Maintains some sort of event ordering, which is irrelevant.

#### Pseudocode usage

Registration, dispatching and deregistration:

```
class EventDispatcher {

    static Map<Event, Collection<Listener>> map;

    static void registerListener(Collection<Event> eventTypes, Listener listener) {

        eventTypes.forEach(et -> map.put(et, listener));
    }

    static void dispatch(SomeEvent event) {

        map.get(SomeEvent.getClass()).forEach(l -> l.trigger(event));
    }

    static void deregisterListener(Listener listener) {

        while (map.values().remove(listener));
    }
}
```

Getting the global insertion-ordered listeners is done via:

```
new LinkedHashSet<>(map.values());
```

as `map.values()` returned a flattened collection and `Set` collapses duplicates.

As noted above, the dispatching is efficient as only listeners which registered to receive an event will receive it. Deregistration has the problem of not knowing from which keys to remove the specified listener, so iteration over all keys is needed, which is not efficient. It is possible to invert the mapping, but I believe it can't be faster.

Maintaining the inverse mapping instead,

```
Map<Listener, Collection<Event>>
```

is preferred when

- The frequency of listener de/registration is high compared to event dispatching.
- The number of event types is high compared to the number of (concurrent) registered listeners.
- The number of event types listeners register to is low compared to the number of event types.

#### Implementations

The Java Collections framework offers several implementations that maintain insertion order. For the map, only `LinkedHashMap` is viable. For the values collection, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and `LinkedHashSet` are viable.

Of the above, Guava offers [multimap implementations](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#implementations-1) for `LinkedHashMap` with `LinkedList` or `LinkedHashSet`. The latter guarantees no duplicate values. Since my listeners are unique by design (as mentioned, they have a unique `int id` used for `equals`), there is no need for the explicit guarantee. There are also iteration order differences between them, but I believe they manifest only if a listener can partially deregister (from specific event types), which is not my case.

For the O(10-100) order of magnitude that I'm dealing with, there is little consideration for performance differences and I've yet to choose the specific implementation.

Answer (score 4):

If I well understood your question, the best structure seems to be an array of lists of `AbstractListener`.

```
List<AbstractListener>[]
```

---

Here a description requirement by requirement:

**Requirement:** Listeners can register and deregister during runtime.

A List can handle [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) and [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) without problems

**Requirements:** The order in which listeners register must be maintained since it is the order in which they receive events (listeners are always added at the end, but can be removed from anywhere).

A List mantains the order. From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

> An ordered collection (also known as a sequence)

**Requirement:** An event type can have 0 or more listeners registered to receive it at any time.

A List can hold 0 or more elements.

**Requirement:** The order of the columns must be maintained.

A List mantains the order of elements.

**Requirement:** Columns can be added and removed.

A List can add or remove elements (columns)

**Requirement:** The order of the rows is irrelevant.

No problem with any data structure

**Requirement:** The number of rows is constant during runtime.

An array has constant size

---

From your comments to the answer is seems that another possible solution is to define a class that holds all events:

```
public interface Listener {
    public void handleEvent(Event event);
}

public class EventGenerator {
    private List<Listener> listeners;

    public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void doSomething(Event event) {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.handleEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Than for each kind of event you can do something like that:

```
// Create an event generator for each kind of event
EventGenerator eventGenerator1 = new EventGenerator();

EventGenerator eventGenerator2 = new EventGenerator();

// Register listeners to eventGenerators
eventGenerator1.addListener(listener1);
eventGenerator1.addListener(listener2);
eventGenerator1.addListener(listener3);

eventGenerator2.addListener(listener1);
eventGenerator2.addListener(listener2);
eventGenerator2.addListener(listener3);

...

// Eventually remove a listener
eventGenerator2.removeListener(listener2);

...

// When doSomething is invoked all listeners on that eventGenerator are invoked
eventGenerator1.doSomething(event1);  // Dispatched to listener 1, 2 and 3
eventGenerator1.doSomething(event2);  // Dispatched to listener 1, 2 and 3
eventGenerator1.doSomething(event3);  // Dispatched to listener 1, 2 and 3
eventGenerator1.doSomething(event4);  // Dispatched to listener 1, 2 and 3

eventGenerator1.removeListener(listener3);

eventGenerator1.doSomething(event5);  // Dispatched to listener 1, 2

eventGenerator1.removeListener(listener1);

eventGenerator1.doSomething(event6);  // Dispatched to listener 2
```

Comment: I am confused by your suggestion. The array is the size of the amount of event types I have, and each cell holds a list of the listeners registered to the event? If so, (1) This is still missing the global listener ordering (the second point in "My thoughts are:"). (2) How do you know which event type corresponds to which index in the array? If I need to dispatch a `SomeTypeEvent`, which cell do I access?

Comment: For (1), do you suggest a separate `List`? I will need to maintain listeners in both at the same time. This is why I thought of combining the `Event -> Listeners` and `List<listeners>` into a single data structure.

Comment: (1) What you call an OrderCollectionType in your second thoughs is a List. (2) Is you that build the array, so you can easily know what (what event handler) is present in the first, in the second, in the third position of the array.

Comment: (1) Yes, that's what I meant in my second comment here. That would mean that when I deregister a listener I will need to remove it from both the global List and from each list in the array. Same when I register. Isn't maintaining the 2 separate data structures dangerous? (2) Yes, but I will need to keep a mapping from event type to the index, or do *a lot* of `instanceof` checks on the event type to get the right index. Isn't just a `Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<Listener>>` better in this case?

Comment: About your edit, when a `Listener` is deregistered it is removed from all the events listening duties. This means that whenever I deregister a `Listener` I will need to call the `removeListener` on *all* the `EventGenerator`s.

Comment: EventGenerator is a class holding all listeners of a particular type (imagine a Button that holds all listeners on the click event). If you remove a listener from the EventGenerator all subsequents events will not call that listener.

Comment: "*If you remove a listener from the EventGenerator all subsequents events will not call that listener.*" All subsequent events *of that type*. What about events of other types? If a listener is registered to event 1, 6, 12, and 17, when it deregisters something/someone needs to tell me that I need to call `removeListener` on these exact 4 EventGenerators. This is bullet 3 in "My thoughts".

Comment: So if you need to register or deregister from all event types the visualization is not correct. You should have X or nothing on all cells of the same column. Right?

Comment: I'm looking at it again and it's even more confusing to me. What is `eventGenerator1.doSomething(event5);` and what would be `eventGenerator5.doSomething(event1);`? If each EventGenerator is for each event type, why do they dispatch events of other types?

Comment: An event is not an event type. A button is an eventGenerator. A click is an event. A second button is a second eventGenerator. If a click is done on the first button is of type "from button 1", if is done on second button is of type "from button 2", but a second click can happen on the same button, it is a new event of the same type, for example a second click on button 1 is of type "from button 1"

Comment: "*So if you need to register or deregister from all event types the visualization is not correct. You should have X or nothing on all cells of the same column. Right?*" Each listener class has a predefined set of events it registers to when `register()` is called on it, or nothing when it isn't registered. You can't deregister from a single event.  My "Pseudocode usage" demonstrates it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116583/discussion-between-davide-lorenzo-marino-and-user1803551).

Answer (score 2):

Since a listener can be attached to many event, I would try to "linearize" the problem by making unique the relation between an `Event` and a `Listener`:

```
public final class Relation {
    private final Class<? extends Event> eventType;
    private final Listener listener;

    public Relation(Class<? extends Event> eventType, Listener listener) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public Class<? extends Event> getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    public Listener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Relation) {
            Relation that = (Relation) obj;

            return this.eventType.equals(that.eventType) && this.listener.equals(that.listener);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(eventType, listener);
    }
}
```

The `EventManager` should encapsulate the whole data structure used to store these relations

```
public final class EventManager {

    private Set<Relation> relations = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public void dispatch(Event e)
    {
        relations.stream()
                 .filter(r -> r.getEventType().isInstance(e))
                 .forEach(r -> r.getListener().processEvent(e));
    }

    public void register(Class<? extends Event> e, Listener l)
    {
        relations.add(new Relation(e, l));
    }

    public void unregister(Listener l)
    {
        relations = relations.stream()
                             .filter(r -> !r.getListener().equals(l))
                             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Event e1 = new Event1();
        Event e2 = new Event2();
        Event e4 = new Event4();
        Listener l1 = new Listener1();
        Listener l2 = new Listener2();
        Listener l3 = new Listener3();
        Listener l5 = new Listener5();
        EventManager em = new EventManager();

        em.register(Event1.class, l1);
        em.register(Event1.class, l3);
        em.register(Event1.class, l5);
        em.register(Event2.class, l2);
        em.register(Event2.class, l3);
        em.register(Event2.class, l5);
        em.register(Event4.class, l5);

        System.out.println("After register");
        em.dispatch(e1); //prints hello from 1, 3, 5
        em.dispatch(e2); //prints hello from 2, 3, 5
        em.dispatch(e4); //prints hello from 5

        em.unregister(l3);

        System.out.println("After unregistering l3");
        em.dispatch(e1); //prints hello from 1, 5
        em.dispatch(e2); //prints hello from 2, 5
        em.dispatch(e4); //prints hello from 5

        em.unregister(l5);

        System.out.println("After unregistering l5");
        em.dispatch(e1); //prints hello from 1
        em.dispatch(e2); //prints hello from 2
        em.dispatch(e4); //prints nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not preserve the ordering requirements. (1) That for each event the listeners will be called in order of addition to the data structure. (2) That there is a global ordering on the listeners.

Comment: @user1803551 I updated the data structure used so that the insertion order is preserved.

Comment: There is still no global ordering for the listeners. And you are relating listeners to specific events and not to event types. Events are instances of event types and are "one time use". You probably want to change the relation to the classes of the events,

Comment: @user1803551 Ok I updated my answer by storing the event types instead of instances. I don't get your point with the global ordering: as I only have one collection, all listeners are already globally ordered by insertion or ?

Comment: See my second point in "My thoughts". Listeners need to be ordered globally by insertion (or I can attempt to sort by id), not only per event type. This is why this is not a simple problem (the other answer missed it too). If it weren't for this, a simple multimap would have done. It can be done by maintaining another `List`, but I was looking for a data structure that would take care of all of it.